# Was Google involved in the making of The Internship?

Tags: the-internship

Considering that the movie heavily revolves around the company, was Google involved with the making of the movie?  Is the intership problem anything like what they actually do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an [**interview**](http://www.movieweb.com/news/exclusive-director-shawn-levy-talks-google-and-the-internship) with director [Shawn Levy](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0506613/):

> **You talked about how one of your first objectives was to lock down Google, but were they reluctant to come on board at all? They're never really been out there like this.**
>
> - You know, this was a big risk, and, in retrospect, I'm still kind of amazed. I wouldn't say that they were reluctant, but they were definitely not like, *'Choose us, choose us!'*
>
>   [...] **They were open to the idea.** I told them straight up, *'The movie might be R rated. It might be a very dicey PG-13.'* Whatever it's rating, it needed to be irreverent, there was certainly going to be a major sequence in a strip club, it's going to have to have enough audacity to be funny.
>
>   To their credit, they said, *'Just make it funny, and make it good-hearted.'* [...] Those were the ground rules and, beyond that, **they were really, impressively, cool with me calling the shots, and me making the movie in the way I saw fit.** [...]
>
> **How close would you say that the real Google internship program is to the version you have in the movie?**
>
> - Here's what is real, and here's what is completely not real.
>
>   What is real is that only something like 10% or less of the interns get jobs. It is real that they are put in teams, and that they spend their internship doing tasks that mirror the jobs of real Googlers. It is real that they wear those crazy beanies.
>
>   **What is not real, is it is not a hyper-competitive, team vs. team structure. The interns are observed as individuals, and they don't compete in this mental *Hunger Games*-like war.**